# Can't read excel(xls) file with pandas, read_excel method

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read excel, ~~~.xls file with python pandas.
but errors are occuring... please help me.

I think encoding of original file is the problem, because when I re-save the file as xlsx with Excel, then no error occurs.

but I can't find the way to solve this problem without re-saving.
I have many- files to work, so I can't re-save all the files.
(If the only way to solve this problem is re-saving, I'd work manually with excel rather than use python.)

the actual file(test.xls) is attached as below (hyperlink)
[test.xls](http://blogattach.naver.net/980d8432221312a78b6a0f3e01e392eb4519ee38/20210112_33_blogfile/kinphw_1610444479622_N2L08T_xls/test.xls)

and my codes are as belows.. it's very simple.
(this sheet_name is KOREAN, so i thought sheet_name is the problem.
but I changed sheet name like "111"... but the error is remaining.)

==CODE1==

```
import pandas as pd
item= "C:\\test\\test.xls"
df1 = pd.read_excel(item, sheet_name="계열별신용공여(38,76,77)", header=None)
```

==CODE2==

```
import xlrd
item= "C:\\test\\test.xls"
df1 = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=item)
```

pandas error is as belows.

===

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_excel(item, sheet_name="계열별신용공여(38,76,77)", header=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1114, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 25, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 38, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 182, in open_workbook
    ignore_workbook_corruption=ignore_workbook_corruption,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 104, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.parse_globals()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1239, in parse_globals
    self.handle_supbook(data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1119, in handle_supbook
    shname, pos = unpack_unicode_update_pos(data, pos, lenlen=2)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\biffh.py", line 324, in unpack_unicode_update_pos
    strg = unicode(data[pos:pos+2*nchars], 'utf_16_le')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal UTF-16 surrogate


>>> df1 = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=item)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 182, in open_workbook
    ignore_workbook_corruption=ignore_workbook_corruption,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 104, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.parse_globals()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1239, in parse_globals
    self.handle_supbook(data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1119, in handle_supbook
    shname, pos = unpack_unicode_update_pos(data, pos, lenlen=2)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\biffh.py", line 324, in unpack_unicode_update_pos
    strg = unicode(data[pos:pos+2*nchars], 'utf_16_le')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

Comment: `illegal UTF-16 surrogate` suggests you may have a problem of encode.

Comment: Please try different options with the parameter `encoding`, e.g. `encoding='utf-8'` or `utf-16`, `utf-32`. Kr

Comment: Thanks, but I checked the documentation of pandas, pandas.read_excel method has no parameter "encoding".